# Multiprocessing not working for a function calculating cross-product of matrices

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to compare the running time of a non-parallel version and a parallel version of a function. The problem is that, while the parallel function works well with the threading package, the processes just never start after I switch to the multiprocessing package. I am wondering if this is caused by my compiler or anything else. Can anyone run my code to see if it works in other environment? And if it does not, what is the problem within my code?

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process

def single_row(a,b,output):
    for j in range(len(b[0])):
        for k in range(len(a)):
            output[j]=output[j]+a[k]*b[k][j]

#Parallel Matrix Cross Multiplication
def cross_parallel(a,b):
    if len(a[0])==len(b):
        tasks=[None]*len(a)
        T=np.array([[0]*len(b[0])]*len(a))
        for i in range(len(a)):
            tasks[i]=Process(target=single_row,args=(a[i],b,T[i]))
        for task in tasks:
            task.start()
        for task in tasks:
            task.join()
        return T
    else:
        print 'Error: Invalid Matrices'

#Non-parallel Matrix Cross Multiplication
def cross_basic(a,b):
    if len(a[0])==len(b):
        T=np.array([[0]*len(b[0])]*len(a))
        for i in range(len(a)):
            for j in range(len(b[0])):
                for k in range(len(a[0])):
                    T[i][j]=T[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j]
        return T
    else:
        print 'Error: Invalid Matrices'

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    x=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
    y=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
    print cross_basic(x,y)
    print cross_parallel(x,y)
```

Result:

```
[[ 90 100 110 120]
 [202 228 254 280]
 [314 356 398 440]
 [426 484 542 600]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

The version using threading package that works(only different at line 15):

```
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread

def single_row(a,b,output):
    for j in range(len(b[0])):
        for k in range(len(a)):
            output[j]=output[j]+a[k]*b[k][j]

#Parallel Matrix Cross Multiplication
def cross_parallel(a,b):
    if len(a[0])==len(b):
        tasks=[None]*len(a)
        T=np.array([[0]*len(b[0])]*len(a))
        for i in range(len(a)):
            tasks[i]=Thread(target=single_row,args=(a[i],b,T[i]))
        for task in tasks:
            task.start()
        for task in tasks:
            task.join()
        return T
    else:
        print 'Error: Invalid Matrices'

#Non-parallel Matrix Cross Multiplication
def cross_basic(a,b):
    if len(a[0])==len(b):
        T=np.array([[0]*len(b[0])]*len(a))
        for i in range(len(a)):
            for j in range(len(b[0])):
                for k in range(len(a[0])):
                    T[i][j]=T[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j]
        return T
    else:
        print 'Error: Invalid Matrices'

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    x=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
    y=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
    print cross_basic(x,y)
    print cross_parallel(x,y)
```

Result:

```
[[ 90 100 110 120]
 [202 228 254 280]
 [314 356 398 440]
 [426 484 542 600]]
[[ 90 100 110 120]
 [202 228 254 280]
 [314 356 398 440]
 [426 484 542 600]]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using threads, the result matrix `T` is shared in the threads (this means it is basically the same object, using the same memory slots). Thus modification of `T` in a child `Thread` will modify the local version of `T` and you get the correct result.

For subprocesses, each child `Process` gets a new copy of `T`. Thus, the modification of `T` in a subprocess does not modify its local version. To get the correct result, you need to send back the result of your computation, using a `Queue` for instance. But you have to be careful as the order you get back the results is not deterministic.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def single_row(a, b, idx, q):
    N = len(b[0])
    output = np.zeros(N)
    for j in range(len(b[0])):
        for k in range(len(a)):
            output[j] = output[j]+a[k]*b[k][j]
    q.put((idx, output))

# Parallel Matrix Cross Multiplication


def cross_parallel(a, b):
    M = len(a)
    q = Queue()
    if len(a[0]) == len(b):
        tasks = [None]*M
        T = np.array([[0]*len(b[0])]*len(a))
        for i in range(M):
            tasks[i] = Process(target=single_row, args=(a[i], b, i, q))
        for task in tasks:
            task.start()
        T = []
        for i in range(M):
            T += [q.get()]
        for task in tasks:
            task.join()
        T.sort()
        T = np.array([v[1] for v in T])
        return T
    else:
        print('Error: Invalid Matrices')

# Non-parallel Matrix Cross Multiplication


def cross_basic(a, b):
    if len(a[0]) == len(b):
        T = np.array([[0]*len(b[0])]*len(a))
        for i in range(len(a)):
            for j in range(len(b[0])):
                for k in range(len(a[0])):
                    T[i][j] = T[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j]
        return T
    else:
        print('Error: Invalid Matrices')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
    y = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
    print(cross_basic(x, y))
    print(cross_parallel(x, y))
```

This approach can be uneasy to use, for instance, if you do not empty the queue before joining the processes, you can cause deadlocks in your program. I recommend looking at `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrents.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to get high level protocol that manage the communication/number of process in a better way.

```
def single_row2(a, b):
    N = len(b[0])
    output = np.zeros(N)
    for j in range(len(b[0])):
        for k in range(len(a)):
            output[j] = output[j]+a[k]*b[k][j]
    return output

def cross_parallel2(a, b):
    import itertools
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    M = len(a)
    if len(a[0]) == len(b):
        res = executor.map(single_row2, a, itertools.repeat(b))

        return np.array([row for row in res])
    else:
        print('Error: Invalid Matrices')
```